# good component to password reminding in joomla

Tags: php, joomla

I would like to change the default behavior of Joomla's password reminding mechanism. I would like to be provided with checking of the **strength** of a password and (optionally) with captcha capabilities. I was wondering if there's a free component for Joomla which I could install and use out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind hacking around in the core code, then you can look in the `components\com_user\controller.php` file. In the `save()` function, around line 82, it retrieves the user's password. At that point you could insert whatever code you like to check the password strength:

```
$passOK = true;
if($post['password'] != $post['password2']) {
    $msg = JText::_('PASSWORDS_DO_NOT_MATCH');
    $passOK = false;
} else if (strlen($post['password']) < 6 || !preg_match("/[0-9]/", $post['password'])) {
    $msg = "The password is too short, or it doesn't contain any numbers.";
    $passOK = false;
}
if (!$passOK) {
    $return = @$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    if (empty($return) || !JURI::isInternal($return)) {
        $return = JURI::base();
    }
    $this->setRedirect($return, $msg, 'error');
    return false;
}
```